# Eslint react/jsx-one-expression-per-line: allow variables and JSX strings on the same line, but not elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

E.g. for this JSX:

```
<h1>
  Hi {name}
</h1>
```

The `react/jsx-one-expression-per-line` plugin wants it as:

```
<h1>
  Hi
  {' '}
  {name}
</h1>
```

or

```
<h1>
  {`Hi ${name}`}
</h1>
```

I think both of those are ugly. I want to allow the first example. However, I don't want to disable the plugin because I don't want to allow multiple elements on one line:

```
<p>hi</p><p>bye</p>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: add this `"react/jsx-one-expression-per-line": "off"` to rules in your eslint configuration file

Comment: I don't want to disable the plugin because I don't want to allow multiple elements on one line

Comment: add this `"prettier/react"` to the `"extends"` part of your `.eslintrc`. See https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/6456#issuecomment-529075600

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
const welcomeMessage = `Hi ${name}`;
<h1>
  {welcomeMessage}
</h1>
```

Comment: You cannot declare const nor variables inside JSX which makes this useless when trying to add somethig as easy as #{element.id} inside a map. ESLint will expect both # and {element.id} to be alone in new lines (which makes it ugglier and harder to read).

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the rule for that line only:

```js
<h1>
{/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-one-expression-per-line */}
  Hi {name}
</h1>
```